# pass filename to gui to show image

Tags: matlab

I have a gui which already has axes on it...i want to pass a filename to that gui and display it on the axes...here's how i tried it..this is written in an xyz.m file:

```
close current_gui;
 result_image(im2fn);
```

here, current gui is a gui i was working with and result_image is the gui where i want to show the image, im2fn is a variable having the filename of the image...
In result_gui i wrote the following code..

```
function result_image_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(im2fn);
```

The gui is displayed but there is no image shown and also i get an error as Undefined function or variable 'im2fn'....Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because `im2fn` is not part of the local workspace inside `OpeningFcn` - you have made an incorrect assumption about the way `varargin` works. When you use [`varargin`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html), it will be a cell array of the values you passed. See the link for more examples, but in your case you just want to do something like this:

```
% Make sure the user passed us something to display
assert(~isempty(varargin), [mfilename ':NoImageToDisplay'], 'You must pass an image to the ''result_image'' GUI');
% Extract data from varargs
im2fn = varargin{1};
% Show it!
imshow(im2fn);
```